# How to find the sum with Mathematica?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

That hard problem was invented by V. P. Beshkarev (Russia) in 1971:

```
Sum[Tan[(4*j - 3)*Pi/180], {j, 1, 45}] // FullSimplify
```

The result should be 45, but the command is running on my comp without any output for hours. I know its tricky calculation by hand which cannot be mimicked with Mathematica.

Comment: `N[Sum[Tan[(4*j - 3)*Pi/180], {j, 1, 45}]]` gives 45.

Comment: @Carl Lange: Up to  a certain precision, is not so? Did you carefully read the question and its tags?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you're expecting as a result except "The result should be 45". Why do you expect `FullSimplify` to do anything in this case?

Comment: @Carl Lange: A simpler problem of such type is Sum[j,{j,1,100}], where the result should be 5050, not 5050.0 .  Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @CarlLange I guess, it is only about challenging _Mathematica_'s symbolic capabilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest approach is to just divide it up into steps and see which transformations can be done reasonably quickly. First, I define the expression:

```
expr = Sum[Tan[(4*j - 3)*Pi/180], {j, 1, 45}];
```

Verify its result numerically:

```
N[expr]
```

> 45.

This is likely, but not necessarily, exact. Thus, the strategy will be trying to prove that some transformation of `expr - 45` is 0 exactly. Since `expr` is primarily trigonometric, there's a few functions that come to mind immediately. `TrigExpand` does not evaluate quickly, but `TrigToExp` shows a fairly self-similar form of a group of fractions. I find fractions usually become easier to work with after `Apart`, and it turns out that transformation is also reasonably quick. However, after `Apart` the numbers do not precisely add up to anything specific, so the 45 would seem to be a residual effect of several independent parts of this expression.

At this point I tried to see if `Simplify` could sort it out:

```
Simplify[Apart[TrigToExp[expr]] - 45]
```

> 0

Which is an exact result, though derived through somewhat convoluted means, which shows that `expr == 45` exactly, so long as no errors occurred during `TrigToExp` and `Apart`, which are both supposed to be complex safe.

Comment: Sorry, but the code suggested by you is running without any output on my comp during several minutes. The same issue with Apart[TrigToExp[expr]] too. I will try to execute your code in cloud.

Comment: It takes about 5 seconds on an i7 4770K on _Mathematica_ 10.1. It takes about 8.4 on a fresh start of 11.2 for me as well. Not a super easy computation, so I wouldn't be surprised if it takes a little bit, but I'd expect it to take less than 2 minutes on most machines.

Comment: Reproduced in Mathematica online in 6 s.. Simply and strongly.

Comment: Hm. I am very curious. I am on version 11.3 on a 4980HQ (so the single-thread performance should be very similar to the 4770K) and this computation takes 47 seconds (returning the correct result). That's significant slow-down...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher on the cloud it takes like 90s

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Sorry for ny inaccurate timing obtained in the second execution online.

Comment: The result 45 is obtained on my 11.3 (a fresh kernel)  in 89s. My comp is not fast.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html)

```
Sum[Tan[(4*j - 3)*Pi/180], {j, 1, 45}] // RootReduce

(* 45 *)
```

Comment: +1. It is unclear to me how it works.

Comment: @user64494 - Mostly only people at Wolfram know "how it works". It is one of the functions like `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `ComplexExpand`, `TrigReduce`, etc. that are used to find alternate forms of expressions. Experimentation is often required to find which one or which combination is best for a given expression.